# Why Feature/ExampleTest fails on my Laravel app?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-8

I want to implement some tests on my laravel app and I begin a simple tutorial to do it.

Before making custom tests I ran php artisan test to verify the tests examples of Laravel.

I have this feature test :

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_example()
    {   
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);

    }
}
```

And this unit test :

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_example()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Unit test ran great but Feature test fails :

```bash
 FAIL  Tests\Feature\ExampleTest
  ⨯ example

  ---

  • Tests\Feature\ExampleTest > example
  Expected response status code [200] but received 404.
  Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 404.

  at tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php:21
     17▕         // $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
     18▕         
     19▕         $response = $this->get('/');
     20▕ 
  ➜  21▕         $response->assertStatus(200);
     22▕ 
     23▕     }
     24▕ }
     25▕ 


  Tests:  1 failed, 5 warnings, 1 passed
  Time:   0.11s
```

So I made some research and I add `php $this->withoutExceptionHandling();` to figure out :

```bash
   FAIL  Tests\Feature\ExampleTest
  ⨯ example

  ---

  • Tests\Feature\ExampleTest > example
   PHPUnit\Framework\ExceptionWrapper 

  GET http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/myapplication/public

  at vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:98
     94▕ unset($options);
     95▕ 
     96▕ require PHPUNIT_COMPOSER_INSTALL;
     97▕ 
  ➜  98▕ PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main();
     99▕ 



  Tests:  1 failed, 5 warnings, 1 passed
  Time:   0.13s
```

I tried this url on browsers (Chrome, Firefox), it works well.
I also tried it on Insomnia and I have a 200 HTTP response.

I think that the problem is with PHPUnit but but despite my research I can't find the solution.

Has anyone encountered this problem before, or have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

file .env check APP_URL=http://localhost
public function test_login()  {

```
    Artisan::call('migrate');
    User::create([
        "usuario" => "juan",
        "password" => Hash::make('12345678')
    ]);

    $response = $this->post('api/login', [
        'usuario' => 'juan',
        'password' => '12345678'
    ]);

    $response->assertStatus(200)->assertJson([
        'success' => true
    ]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who might come across this (By now am sure OP has figured it out).

**Context:**

If you have Laravel installed in a subfolder the tests will not work. This is because Laravel will not actually make HTTP requests but internally resolve the request whilst somehow removing the root folders. This is why the tests work in their containers as they are at the root directory. For example, you have a URL structure as

```
http://localhost/laravel/public
```

this will be resolved to

```
http://laravel/public
```

even when you have overridden the `APP_URL` environment variable in `phpunit.xml`.

**Solution:**

The only workaround I could find for this is to start the app with `artisan serve` and then set the `APP_URL` environment variable as

```
<env name="APP_URL" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000"/>
```

or by following the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/testing#environment)
In short, you need to use `artisan serve` for development and testing environments to avoid running into such undocumented errors.

**Footnote:**

You can reproduce how I came across this by dumping the response variable

```
dd($this->get("api/endpoint");
```

it will contain information about data passed to the view which would only be available if the request was resolved internally and not through HTTP.